# Change the margins inside cells of a DataGrid (Flex)

Tags: apache-flex, mxml

I am using the following code to insert a DataGrid object into a basic Panel:

```
<mx:DataGrid borderThickness="0"
   height="120" dataProvider="{collection}"
   rowHeight="12" fontSize="9"
   showHeaders="false" verticalGridLines="false">
     <mx:columns>
         <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="field1" headerText="Field 1"/>
         <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="field2" headerText="Field 2"/>
     </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

My point for setting both rowHeight and fontSize properties is that I need the DataGrid to be compact, with very little space between each row. But with this code I end up with most of the text "truncated": only the upper part of the symbols appears on each row, and the rest is cut by some empty space.
This I guess is due to the default margins inside DataGrid cells, that take priority over the text itself when displaying.
Is there a way to fix this problem? And is there any reason why Adobe did not let the margin property be set?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you make a custom item renderer based on mx:label ( if the case for you is text only ) and then set the styles you need. Eg. paddingTop/ left/right/bottom.
You can read about ItemRenderers here: [Using an item renderer with an MX DataGrid control](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf64fe7-7fdf.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf64fe7-7fdd)

Comment: Actually I found out that DataGrid itslef owns the paddingTop/Bottom properties that let me change the padding between rows. Yet Using a custom item renderer allows for more flexibility. Thanks !